# Faunadb conditional statement can't run false condition expression

Tags: next.js, nosql, faunadb

I tried to build fulltext search API using nextjs and faunadb.
I referenced the article ["How to Get a Full-Text Search with FaunaDB"](https://codeboje.de/full-text-search-faunadb/)
My index setting is as below.
[image]
This API will receive two values artist and term(short for search term)
If there is two, it will combined by and statement.
Or it will run there own statement or each value.
Implemented code is as below.

```
const queryCase = req.body.artist && req.body.term ? 1 : req.body.term != undefined ? 2 : 3

const tokens = await serverClient.query(
   Filter(
      Paginate(Match(Index("all_token_by_artist_and_description"), true)),
      Lambda(
         [
            "artist",
            "description",
            "image",
            "seller",
            "creator",
            "category",
            "refId"
         ],
         If(
            Equals(queryCase, 1),
            And(
               Or(
                  ContainsStr(
                     LowerCase(Var("artist")), 
                     req.body.term
                  ),
                  ContainsStr(
                     LowerCase(Var("description")), 
                     req.body.term
                  )
               ),
               Equals(
                  LowerCase(Var('artist')), 
                  LowerCase(req.body.artist)
               )
            ),
            If(
               Equals(queryCase, 2),
               Or(
                  ContainsStr(
                     LowerCase(Var("artist")), 
                     req.body.term
                  ),
                  ContainsStr(
                     LowerCase(Var("description")), 
                     req.body.term
                  )
               ),
               Equals(
                  LowerCase(Var('artist')), 
                  LowerCase(req.body.artist)
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)

res.status(200).json(tokens.data)
```

It couldn't run false condition expression. The false expression works fine
when I switched truth expression and false expression.
I get it fixed by make 3 separate query.

```
if(queryCase == 1){
   tokens = await serverClient.query(
              .....
   )
}else if(queryCase == 2){
   tokens = await serverClient.query(
              .....   
   )             
}else{
   tokens = await serverClient.query(
              .....
   )                
}
```

But I really have no idea what's wrong with the original query.
Can anyone tell me the problem with the query?

Comment: Can you explain what the expected result is? Right now, it looks like the result is always a boolean.

Comment: @eskwayrd It retuns list of pre-indexed value [ ["artist", "description", "image", "seller", "creator", "category", "refId"], ... ] which match with search term and artist.

Comment: What brought you to the conclusion that "it couldn't run false condition expression"? I've tried your query with some made up data designed to evaluate each of the three queryCase values, and it filters correctly. I do note that in the final `Equals` expressions of each `If` expression, you use `LowerCase` on the artist value, but not when use use `ContainsStr`. Are you perhaps not seeing expected values because of a case mismatch?

Comment: @eskwayrd It was gave me invalid expression error. It caused by missing value. So I assign random string to the missing value after the case is determined. eg) If I only get "artist" value from request, assign random string to the "term". And it works. Thank you for helping me. FYI. value in "artist" is come from pre-defined "artist-list", so I don't need to use ContainsStr for "artist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by missing value. So I assigned random string to the missing value after the case is determined.
eg) If I only get "artist" value from request, assign random string to the "term".